# Printing out elements in list in reverse and in a specific format

Tags: python

i have a list containing:

```
lst = [10,6,1]
```

and what I'm trying to do now is to print the list elements in reverse order in a specific format. Below is the output i wanted:

```
Candidate: 1,6,10
```

Basically i want to print out the elements of the list in reverse order together with the string "Candidate" concatenated with it. I tried:

```
lst = [10,6,1]
for i in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):
     print("Candidate: " + str(lst[i])
```

but I'm getting:

```
Candidate: 1
Candidate: 6
Candidate: 10
```

instead of:

```
Candidate: 1,6,10
```

I'm pretty sure it's because of the loop, looping through each element and printing them out causing the new line, but what can be done to achieve my desired output?

Comment: `print("Candidate: " + str(lst[::-1]))` ?

Comment: `print(f"Candidate: {','.join(lst[::-1])}")`.

Comment: @ilja doing so, the square brackets are still remained when printed out.

Comment: @ChristianDean that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension is perfect and it's one of the reason we like Python XD.

```
print("Candidate: " + ",".join([str(i) for i in my_list[::-1]))
```

Comment: it's printing out Candidate: 10,6,1 instead of Candidate:1,6,10 XD

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without `for` loop. You just need to use `sep` argument in `python 3` print function.

```
print('Candidate: ', end='')
print(*reversed(l) , sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reversed` and then convert it to list.

```
lst_rev = list(reversed(lst))
print("Candidate: "+ str(lst_rev)[1:-1])
```

**Output:**

```
Candidate: 1, 6, 10
```

Comment: i specified in the question that the output you showed isn't what i wanted. I wanted Candidate: 1,6,10 instead

Answer (score 0):

clean approach would be :

```
lst = [10,6,1]

reverse_=lst[::-1]
for i in reverse_:
    print("Candidate : {}".format(i))
```

outout:

```
Candidate : 1
Candidate : 6
Candidate : 10
```

Just for fun :

```
lst = [10,6,1]
print(list(map(lambda x:"Candidate : {}".format(x),lst[::-1])))
```

output:

```
['Candidate : 1', 'Candidate : 6', 'Candidate : 10']
```